# Why does a light bulb activate an infrared sensor? Is there a way I can filter this out?

Tags: ir

I've made 3 programs. One is written in python, c++ processing and bash.

Everything seems to be okay but then sometimes I get a signal from the arduino that activates the function to lower down the volume on the python code listening for serial data. This is sometimes random but it seems that I can reproduce the same behavior when I turn the light on. I can cause the same disruption if I wave my hands over it quickly.

How can I filter this? I know that IR is part of the electromagnetic spectrum in which the visible light takes part. The sensor is facing upward for a type of omnidirectional receptor. I've placed a TV IR blackish cover over it but with the same results. Do I need to use the function to hash decode the incoming signal? I suppose that it needs a simple circuit as any other sensor.

I want to discard the possibility of a random activation in my code.

Edit:

Taken into consideration the answers until now I can confirm that this is part of a physical phenomena due to the distance between my light and the device.

As for the solution to my volume problem It seems that I used "0" in the same statement as the ir code I remapped in the python code. It turned out to be part of the IRlib library of the arduino code that returns a "0" when it encounters an unknown signal. (due to protocol specification? - out of useful range? )

The thing is that I can change the if statement value for other than "0" but that won't stop it from returning "0" and that's a disadvantage. The solution that came to me is simply intercepting the signal and use continue to skip this.

Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: This is why IR communications uses actual protocols instead of just presence of the signal.

Comment: Can you explain? I use a library to read IR signals from a remote control of a portable dvd player

Comment: You'll need to find out what encoding the remote uses, that will be trial and error.  You might be better of buying a cheep one that you know the encoding for off eBay or aliexpess.

Comment: Yes mine use the NEC protocol that seems generic because I have another that use the same protocol. I've kinda found my solution so I'll edit my first entry. Thanks

Comment: Remote controls use a carrier wave to make it easier to distinguish IR noise from IR signals. What kind of IR-sensor are you using?

Comment: I salvaged one from a fan and got another from the Microsoft Xbox control kit. To tell you the truth this often happened before with the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a light bulb will put out some infrared light.

Decoding remote control signals isn't that hard - there is a tutorial at instructables - http://www.instructables.com/id/The-Easiest-Way-to-Use-Any-IR-Remote-with-Ardiuno/?ALLSTEPS

This also means you can tell the difference between different buttons.

P.S. - when posting in this forum, it helps to include your code and your wiring.

Comment: Yes that seems to be correct. Thanks for the link and fast answer. 

My bad but I did not know where to point that first issue. With the help received I can propose an answer myself now. So I'll post some code for reference

Answer (score 1):

What kind of light bulb is it?  Try using e.g. an LED instead of incandescent; you might get less IR signal.
Having a more complicated signal that is decoded by the receiver reduces your false positives.

Comment: That's a good idea!! Thanks

This can be reproduced depending on intensity of light, velocity of action(no slow dim), type of artificial light and distance between. We are talking about a physical phenomena here. I'll edit my question to propose an explanation.